# Scaling of moments of normal distribution/Brownian incremenrs

Tags: probability, analysis, normal-distribution, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

Let $B_t$ be Brownian motion for $t\ge0$ so that $B_t-B_s \sim N(0,t-s)$. There are a few formulae out there that show how the $p$-th moment of $E[(B_t-B_s)^p]$ is calculated.

My question is: how do they scale with time, i.e. how does $E[(B_t-B_s)^p]$ relate to $E[B_{(t-s)/2+s}-B_s)^p]$ and so on? An easier way of capturing this would be how does $E[B_{t}^p]$ relate to $E[B_{t/2}^p]$ since we can just look at the first increment. It would be nice to see an answer that only uses the scaling and shifting properties of Brownian motion without using the explicit clunky expressions for the $p$-the moments but any answer would help.

Comment: When -as you say- $B_t-B_s\sim N(0,t-s)$ all other moments should follow from the known moments of the normal distribution with variance $t-s$. There is even a Wikipedia article on that.

Comment: And besides : $\frac{B_t-B_s}{\sqrt{t-s}}\sim N(0,1)$ . Further $\frac{(B_t-B_s)^p}{(t-s)^{p/2}}$ has expectation independent of $t-s$. Thus $E[(B_t-B_s)^p]$ scales with ... ?

Comment: I just found the expression online which I couldn’t find before. It is $\sigma^{2p} (2p-1)!!$, which implies that as $\sigma^2(=t-s)$ doubles, the $p$-th moment increases by a factor of $2^p$. However, your expression would make me think that the $p$-th moment scales by a factor of $2^{p/2}$?

Comment: The expression you found [online](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments) should tell you that the moment is ***zero*** when $p$ is ***odd***. The ***even*** moments of $B_t-B_s$ are $\sigma^p(p-1)!!$. Now plug in $\sigma=\sqrt{t-s}$.

Comment: I see, the expression I found in the other StackExchange answer is for the $2p$-th moment. Hence the $p$-th moment scales with $\sqrt{t-s}$

Comment: No. The $p$-th moment scales with $(t-s)^{p/2}$ when $p$ is even. It is zero when $p$ is odd.